# Prepare statement using postgres and golang

Tags: go

How can i properly create a prepare statement using `sql.DB` on golang?

```
type Repository struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func NewRepository(db *sql.DB) {
    return Repository{db: db}
}


func (r Repository) Create() {
    stmt, err := r.db.Prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(age) VALUES(?)")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error()) // "pq: syntax error at or near \")\""
    }
}
```

I cannot see the syntax error, i've even tried to copy the "automatic query"

Comment: Maybe you need a space after the table name?

Comment: @BurakSerdar tried with space and did not work (same error), i've also tried to remove the column definition...

Comment: The placeholder syntax may vary depending on the DB/driver, try `VALUES ($1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this article](http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html#parameter-placeholder-syntax), the placeholder syntax may vary depending on the database.

For Postgres it should be `VALUES ($1)`.

Comment: the funny part: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare